# MySQL Select doesn't use index on different Where Values

Tags: mysql, database

I have a join query that works perfectly sometimes
Im getting eventKey, label and dataUnit from the table EventKeyReference, valueParam from EventData and timestamp from table EventHeader.
In my where clause I have Unit u.id = 3. This works fine. However, when i try to search for Unit u.id = 1, the query can take up to 20 seconds sometimes.

Searching for id = 3

```
SELECT ek.eventKey, ek.label, ek.dataUnit, ed.valueParam, eh.timestamp
FROM EventKeyReference AS ek 
INNER JOIN UnitReference_EventKeyReference AS urek ON urek.eventKeyReferences_id = ek.id 
INNER JOIN UnitReference AS ur ON ur.id = urek.UnitReference_id
INNER JOIN Unit AS un ON un.id = ur.unit_id INNER JOIN User AS u ON u.id = ur.user_id
INNER JOIN EventData AS ed ON ek.eventKey = ed.keyParam
INNER JOIN EventHeader AS eh ON eh.id = ed.eventHeader_id
WHERE ek.eventKey = 'C004' AND u.id = 3 AND un.serialNumber=221148096
ORDER BY eh.timestamp LIMIT 1;
```

Gives this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| eventKey | label    | dataUnit | valueParam | timestamp           |
+----------+----------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| C004     | Utgang 2 | on/off   | 0          | 2000-01-01 00:01:04 |
+----------+----------+----------+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Searching for id = 1 gives this:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| eventKey | label       | dataUnit | valueParam | timestamp           |
+----------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| C004     | DigitalOut1 | ON/OFF   | 0          | 2000-01-01 00:01:04 |
+----------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (16.04 sec)
```

As you can see, the query takes 16 seconds to execute.

When examining EXPLAIN SELECT, i got this.

```
    mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT ek.eventKey, ek.label, ek.dataUnit, ed.valueParam,    eh.timestamp   FROM EventKeyReference AS ek INNER JOIN UnitReference_EventKeyReference AS urek ON urek.eventKeyReferences_id = ek.id INNER JOIN UnitReference AS ur ON ur.id = urek.UnitReference_id  INNER JOIN Unit AS un ON un.id = ur.unit_id INNER JOIN User AS u ON u.id = ur.user_id INNER JOIN EventData AS ed ON ek.eventKey = ed.keyParam INNER JOIN EventHeader AS eh ON eh.id = ed.eventHeader_id   WHERE ek.eventKey = 'C004' AND u.id = 1 AND un.serialNumber=221148096 ORDER BY eh.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                 | key                | key_len | ref                                | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | const  | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY            | 8       | const                              |      1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eh    | index  | PRIMARY                                       | eh_timestamp       | 9       | NULL                               | 169161 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ed    | ref    | FK794A194417A622D6                            | FK794A194417A622D6 | 9       | fltcoor.eh.id                      |      5 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ur    | range  | PRIMARY,FK83382A0747140EFE,FK83382A073EC5085E | FK83382A0747140EFE | 9       | NULL                               |      3 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | urek  | ref    | PRIMARY,FKAC98AB0E2DFCBD8F,FKAC98AB0E564AEB96 | FKAC98AB0E564AEB96 | 8       | fltcoor.ur.id                      |     11 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | un    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,serialNumber                          | PRIMARY            | 8       | fltcoor.ur.unit_id                 |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ek    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY            | 8       | fltcoor.urek.eventKeyReferences_id |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT ek.eventKey, ek.label, ek.dataUnit, ed.valueParam, eh.timestamp   FROM EventKeyReference AS ek INNER JOIN UnitReference_EventKeyReference AS urek ON urek.eventKeyReferences_id = ek.id INNER JOIN UnitReference AS ur ON ur.id = urek.UnitReference_id  INNER JOIN Unit AS un ON un.id = ur.unit_id INNER JOIN User AS u ON u.id = ur.user_id INNER JOIN EventData AS ed ON ek.eventKey = ed.keyParam INNER JOIN EventHeader AS eh ON eh.id = ed.eventHeader_id   WHERE ek.eventKey = 'C004' AND u.id = 3 AND un.serialNumber=221148096 ORDER BY eh.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                 | key                | key_len | ref                                | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | const  | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY            | 8       | const                              |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eh    | index  | PRIMARY                                       | eh_timestamp       | 9       | NULL                               |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ur    | ref    | PRIMARY,FK83382A0747140EFE,FK83382A073EC5085E | FK83382A0747140EFE | 9       | const                              |    2 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | un    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,serialNumber                          | PRIMARY            | 8       | fltcoor.ur.unit_id                 |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ed    | ref    | FK794A194417A622D6                            | FK794A194417A622D6 | 9       | fltcoor.eh.id                      |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | urek  | ref    | PRIMARY,FKAC98AB0E2DFCBD8F,FKAC98AB0E564AEB96 | FKAC98AB0E564AEB96 | 8       | fltcoor.ur.id                      |   11 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ek    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY            | 8       | fltcoor.urek.eventKeyReferences_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For some reason, when in the query with id = 1 MYSQL goes through some 16.000 rows.

This has been bugging me all day,as I can't find why this would occur. If anything more information I'm glad to provide since I'm far from a Mysql expert myself.

Answer (score 2):

As Jakob stated, if you have 160000 entries for user 1, that might be the choking point for you.  I have rewritten to hopefully help out.  I changed the order to hopefully put the smallest granular piece at the primary position of the query and linked up from that.  I would suspect very FEW records for a given serial number so putting that into the WHERE clause, and adding the JOIN conditions secondary (via the ON / AND clause implemented), should help.

```
SELECT 
      ek.eventKey, 
      ek.label, 
      ek.dataUnit, 
      ed.valueParam, 
      eh.timestamp
   FROM 
      Unit AS un 
         INNER JOIN UnitReference AS ur 
            ON un.id = ur.unit_id
            AND ur.user_id = 3      <==  ADDED USER ID CRITERIA HERE
            INNER JOIN User AS u 
               ON ur.user_id = u.id
            INNER JOIN UnitReference_EventKeyReference AS urek 
               ON ur.id = urek.UnitReference_id
               INNER JOIN EventKeyReference AS ek 
                  ON urek.eventKeyReferences_id = ek.id
                  AND ek.eventKey = 'C004'   <== ADDED EVENT KEY CRITERIA HERE
               INNER JOIN EventData AS ed 
                  ON ek.eventKey = ed.keyParam
                  INNER JOIN EventHeader AS eh 
                     ON ed.eventHeader_id = eh.id
   WHERE 
      un.serialNumber=221148096
   ORDER BY 
      eh.timestamp LIMIT 1;
```

The only other item I would try if the above does NOT work, AND because it is MySQL, I would add one more keyword...

SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN   [rest of query]

which tells MySQL to query in the order you've stated and not try to think for you in a different sequence.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer.I just tried your query, but it gives the same result. About 12 seconds for id=1, and 0.0 seconds for id= 3.  There are many entries, with the same serial number, ie. some 80000 entries with serialNumber= "221148096", and 80000 entries with serialNumber = "220201080" for example.

Comment: Np, thanks for your time! Actually adding STRAIGHT_JOIN decreased the time for the query "id=1" to execute down to about 2 seconds, but increased the time to 2 seconds for id =3! I will investigate this more tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is actually doing what you ask it to do. My suspicion is that you actually have 160000+ rows with u.id = 1 while you only have one row with u.id = 3. Looking at your explain you can see that your query does in fact use index on both queries. But in one case you loop over 160000+ rows since that is how many there are with u.id = 1. I bet that, if you remove your limit 1 clause you will get many many results for the slow query.

Comment: Hello Jakob. I removed the limit for both quries, and actually there is about ca 80000 entries with with id = 1, and ca 80000 entries with id = 3.